# Получить response сервера имитируя поведение сайта

Tags: javascript, http, веб-сервер

Здраствуйте

Моя задача получить с этого сайта (https://www.govmap.gov.il/?c=204000,595000&z=0) информацию о всех точках, то есть кординату и нужный мне слой информации. Конкретно сейчас населения. Насколько я поняла, сайт динамический и что бы получить эту информацию мне нужно имитировать поведения сайта и response сервера. Проблема в том что я нуб и была бы рада если бы кто-то подсказал как это провернуть или хотя бы указал на название нужных мне тем.

Comment: Внизу сайта есть ссылка [https://api.govmap.gov.il/](https://api.govmap.gov.il/) вот она вам и нужна

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, а ты уверен, что Ira владеет ивртом? Там API на ипврите...)))

Comment: @Air Неправда. Там API на JavaScript :)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, Хорошая шутка....)))))))))))))))))